# Why cannot `ExecutorService` consistently schedule threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, cyclicbarrier

I am attempting to reimplement my concurrent code using `CyclicBarrier` which is new to me. I can do without it but am time trialling it against my other solution, the problem I have is a deadlock situation with the following code:

```
//instance variables (fully initialised elsewhere).
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
private ArrayList<IListener> listeners = new ArrayList<IListener>();
private int[] playerIds;

private class WorldUpdater {
    final CyclicBarrier barrier1;
    final CyclicBarrier barrier2;
    volatile boolean anyChange;
    List<Callable<Void>> calls = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();

    class SyncedCallable implements Callable<Void> {
        final IListener listener;

        private SyncedCallable(IListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            listener.startUpdate();
            if (barrier1.await() == 0) {
                anyChange = processCommons();
            }
            barrier2.await();
            listener.endUpdate(anyChange);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public WorldUpdater(ArrayList<IListener> listeners, int[] playerIds) {
        barrier2 = new CyclicBarrier(listeners.size());
        barrier1 = new CyclicBarrier(listeners.size());
        for (int i : playerIds)
            calls.add(new SyncedCallable(listeners.get(i)));
    }

    void start(){
        try {
            exec.invokeAll(calls);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


void someMethodCalledEveryFrame() {
    //Calls some Fisher-something method that shuffles int[]
    shufflePIDs();  
    WorldUpdater updater = new WorldUpdater(listeners, playerIds);
    updater.start();
}
```

I use the debugger in Android Studio (intelliJ) to pause execution at this stage. I get multiple threads showing the my `await` calls as the last of my code to be executed

> ->`Unsafe.park`
>
> ->`LockSupport.park`
>
> ->`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await`
>
> ->`CyclicBarrier.doWait`
>
> ->`CyclicBarrier.await`

At least one thread will be have this stack:

->`Unsafe.park`.

->`LockSupport.park`

->`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await`

->`LinkedBlockingQueue.take`

->`ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask`

->`ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker`

->`ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run`

->`Thread.run`

I notice that the `CyclicBarrier` plays no part in these latter stray threads.

`processCommons` **is** calling `exec.invokeAll` (on the 3 listeners),  I suppose this means I am running out of threads. But many times this doesn't happen so please could someone clarify why `ExecutorService` cannot consistently schedule my threads? They have their own stack and program counter so I would have thought this to not be a problem. I only ever have max 4 running at once. Someone help me with the math?

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `listeners.size()` when your `WorldUpdater` is created?  If it is more than four, then your threads will never get past the barrier.

Your `ExecutorService` has *exactly* four threads.  No more, no fewer.  The callers of `barrier1.await()` and `barrier2.await()` will not get past the barrier until exactly `listeners.size()` threads are waiting.

My gut reaction is, it would be a mistake for pool threads to use a `CyclicBarrier`.  `CyclicBarrier` is only useful when you know exactly how many threads will be using it.  But, when you're using a thread pool, you often do *not* know the size of the pool.  In fact, in a real-world (i.e., commercial) application, if you're using a thread pool, It probably was not created by your code at all.  It probably was created somewhere else, and passed in to your code as an *injected dependency*.

Comment: I initially approved this because of your emphasis on "_exactly_ four", "No more, no fewer", which appeared profound. I now realise it is just wrong: _like_ my attempt to use `CyclicBarrier`. It just doesn't fit here, so thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment and came up with:

```
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("startUpdate, Thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            listener.startUpdate();
            if (barrier1.await() == 0) {
                System.out.println("processCommons, Thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
                anyChange = processCommons();
            }
            barrier2.await();
            System.out.println("endUpdate, Thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            listener.endUpdate(anyChange);
            return null;
        }
```

Which revealed when using a pool of 3 with 3 `listeners`, I will always hang in `processCommons` which contains the following:

```
    List<Callable<Void>> calls = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
    for (IListener listiner : listeners)
        calls.add(new CommonsCallable(listener));
    try {
        exec.invokeAll(calls);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With 2 threads waiting at the barrier and the third attempting to create 3 more. I needed one extra thread in the `ExecutorService` and the 2 at the barrier could be "recycled" as I was asking in my question. I've got references to 6 threads at this stage when `exec` is only holding 4. This can run happily for many minutes.

```
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

Should be better, but it was not.

Finally I did breakpoint stepping in intelliJ (thanks ideaC!)

The problem is

```
        if (barrier1.await() == 0) {
            anyChange = processCommons();
        }
        barrier2.await();
```

Between the 2 `await` you may get several suspended threads that haven't actually reached the `await`. In the case of 3 listeners out of a pool of 4 it only takes one to get "unscheduled" (or whatever) and `barrier2` will never get the full complement. But what about when I have a pool of 8? The same behaviour manifests with all but two of the threads the stack of limbo:

->Unsafe.park.

->LockSupport.park

->AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await

->LinkedBlockingQueue.take

->ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask

->ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker

->ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run

->Thread.run

What can be happening here to disable all 5 threads? I should have taken James Large's advice and avoided crowbarring in this over elaborate `CyclicBarrier`.--UPDATE-- It *can* run all night now without `CyclicBarrier`.